# How long has Windows 7 been locked?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-7

Is there a way to find out either programatically (batch file, VBS), or by means of a 3rd-party tool how long a workstation has already been locked (using the Win+L shortcut)? The output of the script or the 3rd-party tool should be f.e. 60 minutes, if the workstation is locked since 60 minutes.

Thanks!

Comment: can you be more clear? You want to know if we can shutdown a computer?

Comment: I have revised the question. No, the script should not shut down the computer. I just want to know how long the workstation is already locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this VBScript for knowing if the workstation is locked.. and if yes, since when it was locked.
This script will check for the process `LogonUI.exe` which is created when workstation is locked and gets the creation date of that process.

```
Dim strReturn : strReturn = "."
Dim computer : computer = "."
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 Then
    computer = WScript.Arguments(0)
End If

Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmStart)
    WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmStart, 5, 2) & "/" & _
    Mid(dtmStart, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmStart, 4) _
    & " " & Mid (dtmStart, 9, 2) & ":" & _
    Mid(dtmStart, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmStart, 13, 2))
End Function

Function IsWorkstationLocked( computer )
    Dim wmi : Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://" & computer & "/root/cimv2")
    Dim logonScreenCount
    Set logonScreenCount = wmi.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'LogonUI.exe'")
    for each xxx in logonScreenCount
        StartTime = xxx.CreationDate
        strReturn = WMIDateStringToDate(StartTime)
        creationTime = xxx.CreationDate
        Next
    IsWorkstationLocked = (logonScreenCount.Count > 0)
End Function

If IsWorkstationLocked(computer) Then
    Wscript.Echo "locked since " & strReturn
Else
    Wscript.Echo "not locked"
End If
```

HTH!

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for this. But how can I call the script if the workstation is locked?

Comment: you can pass the computer name remotely in the arguments and check.

Comment: Or, you can use the same logic in while loop (like an event listener) and make it record the time when the workstation is locked..

Comment: Hmmm. I dont get it to run with the computer name. I'm trying to run your script from a different workstation which is on the same network as the locked workstation. For the computer name I have passed the hostname of the locked workstation. But this doesn' work. I get an error saying "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable: 'GetObject'.

Comment: can you check if the machine is reachable by pinging the machine?

Comment: Yes, I can ping the machine using its hostname.

Comment: If this is relevant. All machines belong to the same workgroup. If I unlock the workstation, open a cmd windows and start the script passing its hostname it runs and says "not locked".

Comment: This script runs on windows 7 SP1 machines only.. what OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64Bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72613/discussion-between-karthik-manchala-and-rickson1982).

Comment: I have revised the code and adapted the formatting according to [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/07/20/how-can-i-determine-the-date-and-time-that-a-process-started.aspx). On the remote machine, the RemoteAdmin service must be enabled.